# Server config for WCF application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, iis

This is a really important questions and I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

A developer had developed a service for me which runs in Windows Server. It communicates with sql server database and passes the data to client application. The client application run on windows and communicates with server database using that service. The person had developed two programs coded in C#. One was service which is configured and installed in server and other is a dll that winforms applications uses to get data and perform other functions.

Currently the who setup is working fine. A windows server (2008 R2) is running with SQL Server 2012 (Express). It also has IIS and the service is configured. This is what is present/configured:

- Inetpub folder has a folder where service files are present. It has bin folder with dll file and root folder has wcf service file (svc) and web.config file.
- IIS has the service configured in application pool and sites
- SQL Server is running and SQL Server Management Studio is also installed

The server configuration etc was done by the developer few years ago. Now I wish to shift to another server. So I am trying to configure this in another Windows server (this time Windows Server 2016) and am using Sql Server 2016.
Inspite of me trying to configure the server the same way it is doing in older server (which is running ok) the program is unable to communicate with the new server. I have checked the IIS config, have imported the database in the new server, create users and matched setting. The web config file was tweaked to match new server name. The firewall has port opened. But still it is not working.

I wonder what I am missing or have not yet configured. For e.g. the program uses a port e.g. 1670 and firewall has this port opened but I have not registered this port in new server for WCF. Is this the issue or what? The IIS setting is all done as they match with old server IIS settings.

Please help me in anyway you can. Even when I am trying to run the program locally (on server) to test it, it gives error (network error). The old server (orig) however is working fine.

Thank you.

Comment: There's not enough information here to go in.  Is the servername / address configurable in the application, or hardcoded?  Did you name the new server exactly?  Is it on the same LAN/VLAN?  Have the same IP/Hostname?  This doesn't appear suited for StackOverflow, in the end - more likely better on ServerFault.. but definitely not without a LOT more information and details.

Comment: Please read [ask] and include the actual errors and your research for them.

Comment: Try installing `WCFTestClient` (google it to see how to get it and install it) on the Application server.  It will record WCF errors occurring on the WCF Service. This may help.

Comment: The old server is hosted by another company and new server is hosted by amazon. The config file has connection string which I modified as per new server name and new connection (SQL). The Service URL which is passed (i.e. ip address) is not hardcoded.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not showing the full question. An edited version of what I wrote is being shown.

Comment: No, I edited your question. Half of it is irrelevant, and the relevant parts are missing.

Comment: System.ServiceModel.FaultException was caught
 HResult=-2146233087
 Message=The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs. Source=mscorlib

Comment: So, did you try to read and understand that exception? There is an underlying error which you need to obtain and research. Without it, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I did a bit of tweaking in config file. Now when I run the program it gives error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. It runs fine when given old server's ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I enabled mixed mode authentication in SQL Server. :)